# Is Inserting text into a Google Doc onEdit() possible?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-drive-realtime-api

What I'm trying to do is catch a user's input, and maybe replace the input with some other text. 
Like expand abbreviations, or enter the timestamp for each line at the beginning of the line.

The Google app script API doesn't seem to provide a way to get the most recent entered text and parse it. The main page mentions that polling seems to be the only way to implement it. Though, I haven't spent a lot of time on it, and if anyone can point me to something useful, I would appreciate it.

I've also heard that the Google Drive API can make this possible.

But is it possible to easily capture entered text and replace with something else?

Answer (score 0):

There's a polling example in [How to poll a Google Doc from an add-on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24773177/how-to-poll-a-google-doc-from-an-add-on/24773178#24773178).

Recognizing "most recently entered text" would require you to produce diffs between what-was and what-is. A diff library such as [**jsdiff**](http://ejohn.org/projects/javascript-diff-algorithm/) with its `diffString( String oldFile, String newFile )` function would help identify what's changed - then you could search for it and perform your adjustments. All while the user keeps typing... tricky!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I considered doing it that way , but ran into several problems.  Thanks for the help anyway!