# How can I change a textBox when a user selects a new cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a small GUI made in google scripts for a spreadsheet.  I have several text fields that I would like to dynamically change, whenever a user selects a new cell in the spreadsheet. I am basically asking if there is a trigger or event handler that can fire each time a user selects a new cell. I have searched, but can't seem to find how to do this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you for editing, but perhaps an answer is out there?

Comment: same here... wrong tag, use google apps script. but this one I'm afraid the answer won't please you : there is no such trigger.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such trigger in spreadsheet and UiApp won't allow you to get that functionality.

But there is a possible workaround by polling the spreadsheet from an HTML sidebar in the new version of spreadsheets : see [this brilliant answer by Mogsdad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24773177/how-to-poll-a-google-doc-from-an-add-on/24773178#24773178)...

Of course it implies quite a lot of changes in your existing script... HTML Service works with client JavaScript and html,which has not much in common with UiApp.

Comment: Dang! Just as I was about to click "save"... you beat me to it! How am I ever supposed to catch up?

Comment: Ha ha ! excellent ! I retagged this one myself so I read it before it was even visible here... but since I mention you in my answer it's almost as if you answered it ! right ?  but you're right, I spent too much time on this forum today answering all around... (but it was raining and I didn't feel like doing something else ;-)

Comment: My man Serge, just answering all my google script questions today haha, thank you both!