# OnSheetActivate Event?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-apps-script-addon

I am looking for an event that is triggered on sheet change or sheet activate. I have tried the installable trigger onChange(https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change) and it actually triggers an event when a new sheet is inserted. This does not handle sheet change among existing sheets.

Has anyone got this working? Any inputs on this is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to capture change tab event in Google Spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26506382/how-to-capture-change-tab-event-in-google-spreadsheet)

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to capture a sheet change event. Not unless you have a script checking the active sheet running all the time, but then you meet daily runtime limits.