# Convert HTML with bold style to Google Doc using Google Script

Tags: html, css, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs

I'm trying to convert HTML codes into Google Doc using `Google Apps Script` but I'm losing the bold CSS styles. Everytime I get the converted Google Doc file, it's converting the text perfectly but missing bold styles from every text. Here's my code,

```
function html_to_doc() {
    var html = '<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type"><style type="text/css">ol{margin:0;padding:0}table td,table th{padding:0}.c9{-webkit-text-decoration-skip:none;color:#0000ff;font-weight:700;text-decoration:underline;vertical-align:baseline;text-decoration-skip-ink:none;font-size:12pt;font-family:"Arial";font-style:normal}.c11{color:#ff0000;font-weight:700;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:baseline;font-size:11pt;font-family:"Arial";font-style:normal}.c6{color:#000000;font-weight:700;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:baseline;font-size:36pt;font-family:"Arial";font-style:normal}.c3{color:#000000;font-weight:400;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:baseline;font-size:11pt;font-family:"Arial";font-style:normal}.c4{color:#000000;font-weight:400;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:baseline;font-size:11pt;font-family:"Arial";font-style:italic}.c2{color:#000000;font-weight:700;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:baseline;font-size:11pt;font-family:"Arial";font-style:normal}.c0{padding-top:24pt;padding-bottom:6pt;line-height:1.0;page-break-after:avoid;text-align:left}.c1{padding-top:0pt;padding-bottom:0pt;line-height:1.0;text-align:left}.c5{padding-top:12.8pt;padding-bottom:12.8pt;line-height:1.0;text-align:center}.c10{background-color:#ffffff;max-width:468pt;padding:72pt 72pt 72pt 72pt}.c8{font-weight:700;font-style:italic}.c7{height:11pt}.title{padding-top:24pt;color:#000000;font-weight:700;font-size:36pt;padding-bottom:6pt;font-family:"Arial";line-height:1.0;page-break-after:avoid;text-align:left}.subtitle{padding-top:18pt;color:#666666;font-size:24pt;padding-bottom:4pt;font-family:"Georgia";line-height:1.0;page-break-after:avoid;font-style:italic;text-align:left}li{color:#000000;font-size:11pt;font-family:"Arial"}p{margin:0;color:#000000;font-size:11pt;font-family:"Arial"}h1{padding-top:12pt;color:#000000;font-weight:700;font-size:24pt;padding-bottom:12pt;font-family:"Arial";line-height:1.0;text-align:left}h2{padding-top:11.2pt;color:#000000;font-weight:700;font-size:18pt;padding-bottom:11.2pt;font-family:"Arial";line-height:1.0;text-align:left}h3{padding-top:12pt;color:#000000;font-weight:700;font-size:14pt;padding-bottom:12pt;font-family:"Arial";line-height:1.0;text-align:left}h4{padding-top:12.8pt;color:#000000;font-weight:700;font-size:12pt;padding-bottom:12.8pt;font-family:"Arial";line-height:1.0;text-align:left}h5{padding-top:12.8pt;color:#000000;font-weight:700;font-size:9pt;padding-bottom:12.8pt;font-family:"Arial";line-height:1.0;text-align:left}h6{padding-top:18pt;color:#000000;font-weight:700;font-size:8pt;padding-bottom:18pt;font-family:"Arial";line-height:1.0;text-align:left}</style><div><p class="c1 c7"><span class="c3"></span></p></div><h4 class="c5"><span class="c9">This is a test title of H4</span></h4><p class="c1"><span class="c3">This is a paragraph!</span></p><p class="c1"><span class="c2">This is a BOLD paragraph!</span></p><p class="c1"><span class="c11">This is red text! REDRUM!!!</span></p><p class="c1 c7"><span class="c3"></span></p><p class="c1"><span class="c4">This is italic</span></p><p class="c1"><span class="c8">This is italic bold!</span></p><p class="c1 c7"><span class="c3"></span></p><p class="c0 title" id="h.pfc0hsq1vh6g"><span>This is a big TITLE</span></p>';
    var mediaData = Utilities.newBlob("").setDataFromString(html, "UTF-8").setContentType("text/html");
    var resource = {
     title: "Html_to_doc",
    };
    var optionalArgs = {
     convert: true
    };
    var newFileId = Drive.Files.insert(resource, mediaData, optionalArgs);
}
```

How can I resolve this issue? How can I get the bold texts from the original html code?

Comment: try changing all `font-weight: 700` to `font-weight: bold`

Comment: While I believe @AswinKumar 's answer is right ([documentation for his answer here](https://www.quirksmode.org/css/text/fontweight.html)), could you try to update your question to have the html written in a more organized way (maybe use a beautifier) so that any other issue with it can be identified? Additionally, if that doesn't do it, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082353/how-do-i-make-text-bold-in-html?answertab=votes#tab-top) is a question that talks about setting html bold.