# Open an image in Google Docs

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

Just a little background: As you might know, if you have an image in Google drive and you try to open it with Google Docs, Google tries to extract the text within your image (OCR) and show the text alongside the image in a newly created Google Docs file.

I am writing a script and within that script I would like to open an image (with some text) with Google Docs.

When I try to do it through the following code, I just an Error message with no explanation on why it fails.

```
var file_url = file.getUrl();
try
{
    var doc = DocumentApp.openByUrl(file_url);
}catch (e) {
    Logger.log("Error Occurred: " + e.toString());
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit 1: Here is an actual scenario. I have the following .png image and I can open it with Google Docs.

[image]

When I open with Google Docs, I get the following document:

[Document generated after opening the .png image with Google Doc.](https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vR8zOZHG6NyJENHKsVjDH6r6neNk2U6jUTGeevh3xljWzt6Ffb1-B5-wtPaQ9dOolAAdlJ_2VB-6fW_/pub)

Having the url of this .png file, I would like to do all this through my script so I can have the OCR generated text.

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your situation, can I ask you about your issue? 1. About ``I would like to open an image (with some text) with Google Docs.``, do you want to insert an image to Google Document? About this, can you provide a sample result you want? 2. What is ``file_url`` of ``var doc = DocumentApp.openByUrl(file_url);``?

Comment: @Tanaike, I have updated my question to show what I need to achieve. The `file_url` is just a url of an image file in Google Drive.

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your question. I proposed a modified script. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

- You want to convert a PNG file to Google Document by OCR using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? In this modification, Drive API is used.

**When you use this script, please enable Drive API at Advanced Google Services and API console. You can see about this at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51737410/7108653).**

#### Modified script:

```
var fileId = "### file ID of PNG file ###";
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
Drive.Files.insert(
  {title: file.getName(), mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS},
  file.getBlob(),
  {ocr: true}
);
```

#### Note:

- When the URL of PNG file is like `https://drive.google.com/file/d/#####/view?usp=sharing`, `#####` is the file ID.
- In this modified script, the filename of created Document uses the filename of file retrieved by `fileId`. If you want to use other filename, please modify `title: file.getName()`.

#### References:

- [Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/)

Comment: @Sep Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: @Sep Is there anything that I can do for your question? If my answer was not useful for your situation. I have to apologize and modify it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. I would like to think of about the solution.

Comment: your answer works with one modification, replace `GOOGLE_DOCS` with `document` :) Thank you for this!