# HTML Loading Messages

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to pass a value back to a [HTML page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) while a server side function is running?

In the past when I was using the [UI](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/ui-service) service, early in the function I would just create a label in the UI like:

```
app.createLabel('Working, hang on!');
```

And it would appear *while* the script was running, letting them **know** the script was running. When it got to certain parts of the script I would then be able to update/create a new message like:

```
app.createLabel('Halfway there, hold on.');
```

Or

```
app.createLabel('Fetched values, processing them');
```

etc., to tell them where we are if the script was running for a long time. An added bonus was that it could also update them on what direction the script was taking, so for example if a room booking script found that the first room was unavailable, it could pass a message back such as:

```
app.createLabel('First room was busy, checking other rooms');
```

And so on, and so forth.

Is there a way to do this with the HTML service? It seems my only options are [success](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function)) and [failure](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withFailureHandler(Function)) handlers updating the HTML page when the function is complete, which don't seem to be what I want, as it's not a 'Real Time' message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use `ui.alert()` in sheets and docs, and sheets also has `toast()`.

To keep the message within a sidebar or dialog that you've created using the HTML Service, you can set up a separate poller function on the client, to retrieve messages from the server every once in a while. Your long-running function could queue up a message via a function call on the server, which would be picked up by the poller on its next cycle, and displayed to the user.

See [How to poll a Google Doc from an add-on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24773177/how-to-poll-a-google-doc-from-an-add-on/24773178#24773178) for an example of a poller.

Comment: Interesting suggestion. Unfortunate that it adds a layer of complexity on to the relatively simple way that I had it previously, but it certainly looks as though it would work. Though you mention Docs & Sheets bound scripts in the example you've listed, I don't see any reason this wouldn't also work in a stand alone script, correct?