# What is the opposite of google.script.run?

Tags: google-apps-script

google.script.run allows a client script to call a function on the server.

But how do I run a script function on the client side from Google Apps Script?

Comment: Can you explain more about what you are trying to accomplish? While server side code can't directly invoke any client-side functions, there may be other ways to solve your problem.

Comment: @Mogsdad for example your famous **poll** friend ;-) ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24773177/how-to-poll-a-google-doc-from-an-add-on

Answer (score 0):

There's no native way, you'll have to constantly check the GAS for something, eg:

```
var lastReturn;
setInterval(checkChange, 500);

function checkChange(){
   google.script.run.withSuccesshandler(functionToGetAReturnedValue).functionInGSThatWillReturnAValue();
}

function functionToGetAReturnedValue(whatReturned){
   if(whatReturned !== lastReturn){
      doSomething();
      lastReturn = whatReturned;
   }
}
```