# Using google spreadsheet values for a drop down in a Google Docs Side bar

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

There doesnt seem to be much out there r.e. google docs side bars.

Other than the fantastic work done by Mogsdad.

His cursor position tool is 1/2 of what I need already ([How to poll a Google Doc from an add-on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24773177/how-to-poll-a-google-doc-from-an-add-on)).

I have a google sheets template with ~200 possible placeholders that need to be put into the google doc, populated, and then PDF'd.

What I cant seem to find anywhere is how to get ranges from a google sheet into a docs side bar. This way when the template is being built, I can set up some variable dynamic drop downs that would place the correct place holder at the cursor position.

Anyone able to point me in the right direction? (Yes I am aware of Autocrat :P)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Google Apps Script [Spreadsheet service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/), first to open the spreadsheet then to get the range and lastly to get the values.

Example:

```
/**
 * Get the values from a range speficied by the Spreadsheet ID and the range reference or 
 * name
 *
 * @param {'1FkUd199CS3U25bfb5WxP-Jy--qcgD4NTHYWNMw8AtiA'} id Spreadsheet id
 * @param {'Sheet1!A1:A100'} stringReference Reference string
 * @return 2D array with the values of the specified range
 */
function getSpreadsheetValues(id,stringReference){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  var range = ss.getRange(stringReference);
  return range.getValues();
}
```