# How to check instantly the changes made by user in the Google Docs?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, eventtrigger

I need to use Edit event on Google Doc, but the only trigger that i found was onOpen: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_docs_events.
Is there any solution to check instantly the changes made by user in the Doc, not using deprecated The Realtime API and pulling the document or adding submit button?

Comment: go here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ the type triggers in the search box

Comment: Don't think there's any direct trigger , but you could poll: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24773177

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there are no `onEdit()`, `onChange()` triggers for Google Docs.

The triggers available for Google Docs are the following:

- `onOpen()` triggers both simple and installable;
- `time driven` triggers;
- `onInstall()` simple triggers.

What you can do instead is  file a **Feature Request** on [**Issue Tracker**](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113&hl=ca) where you specify the details needed.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers);