# Google form with Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a seat booking system so that user can fill in seat preference on Google form and data would be updated on Google sheet linked to Google form. However the key is that I want to show a real time information in form of matrix (with row and column in grid like fashion to indicate which seat is booked and which is available), so that user can fill the choice correctly in the Google form before submitting the form.

I somehow feel that requirement to show the real time information in form of matrix side by side to Google form may not be possible.

It could be my technical knowledge limitation on Google form and Google sheet. Would appreciate your thoughts on this if this can be achieved.

Thanks

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot imagine your goal. Can I ask you about the detail of `the real time information in form of matrix side by side`? Can you provide the sample output situation as the image? And also, for example, when 2 users are open the Google Form and at first, one of 2 users is submitted, how will you want to do to another user who has already opened the Google Form?

Comment: So imagine a place with capacity of 100 seats in form of 10x10 matrix, so a row can be A, B, C, D etc. and each row can have seats numbered 1, 2, 3, etc. so a particular seat can be A1, B1, C10, D9, F4 etc.. which I would like to show visually on the Google form as the seats gets occupied, so that person doing reservation can choose correctly.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still understand your answer to my 2 questions for trying to understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. If you can give me time to understand your question, I'm glad.

Comment: I am not sure in what other words I can explain you.

Comment: Make a sketch of what you want

Comment: Would you consider providing screenshots to visually clarify what you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Publish [a webapp bound to Google sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web?hl=en)
- Embed the Google form in your webapp
- [Poll your sheet from web app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24773178/) every minute or so.
- Use [LockService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock?hl=en) to avoid simultaneous execution conflicts.

[image]